# Connexion problem with phpGrid-Lite with MS-SQL-Server with PHP 7.3

Tags: sql-server, connection, adodb-php, phpgrid, php-7.3

Someone is using phpGrib with PHP 7.3 and MS-SQL-Sever ?
If yes I have a problem maybe someone can save me.
I have this error :

> { Warning: Use of undefined constant ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN - assumed
>   'ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
>   PHP) in
>   C:\Apache24\localhost***\phpGrid_Lite\server\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on
>   line 4771
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER - assumed
>   'SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
>   PHP) in
>   C:\Apache24\localhost***\phpGrid_Lite\server\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on
>   line 4771 }

I already looked at this page https://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/314967-undefined-constant-odbc-binmode-return-and-sql-cur which was useless because I already have driver for PHP7.3 and MS-SQL-Server as I connected to database with PDO, I uninstall, install again driver and it change nothing (of course I reset Apache)

here the code I put as recommend by phpGrid :

```
define('PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME','localhost'); // database host name
define('PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME', '###');     // database user name
define('PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD', '###'); // database password
define('PHPGRID_DB_NAME', '###'); // database name
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'odbc_mssql_native');  // database type
define('PHPGRID_DB_CHARSET','utf8');
```

I have string instead of ### which are here just for mask data
Also when I connect to database by PDO without phpGrid I have no problem, then I tried to change

```
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'odbc_mssql_native');
```

by

```
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'sqlsrv');
```

then I have the error :

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it. in
>   C:\Apache24\localhost***\phpGrid_Lite\server\adodb5\drivers\adodb-mysqli.inc.php
>   on line 124 Error: Could not connect to the database

Look like it take sqlsrv like mysql.

Then I try

```
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'mssqlnative');
```

Because it's working with adodb and cautious this time I have the super usefull error :

> Error: Could not connect to the database

Someone have an idea or the solution ? I don't have other idea exept have to do all DataGrid myself :( but will be much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check that you have the latest version of the following drivers installed on your server :

ODBC driver (v17) from Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567

SQLSRV v5.50 for PHP 7.3. It's only a preview (but official) 5.50 version:

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.5.0-preview

Note that the way of calling extensions has changed in PHP7.3.
You then have to enable both .DLL in your `php.ini` with these **precise names** :

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64
extension=sqlsrv_73_ts_x64
```